# Compiler can't "see" control in ASP.NET web forms project

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am working on an ASP.NET Web Forms project, and I have the following page which contains a GridView control:

```
<asp:Content ID="ctMain" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMain" runat="server">
    <form runat="server">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1 fs-3 fw-bold text-sm-center">
                    Client Records
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-1 text-end">
                    Display clients whose
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlField" runat="server" CssClass="w-100 form-control text-black">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Last Name" Value="LastName" Selected="true" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="First Name" Value="FirstName" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Email Address" Value="ContactEmail" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Telephone" Value="Telephone" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
                    contains
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbInfo" runat="server" CssClass="w-100 form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 text-start">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Search" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlGrid" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvClients" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="id" PageSize="20"
                                autogeneratecolumns="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowCustomPaging="true" Width="100%"
                                rowstyle-backcolor="Wheat" RowStyle-ForeColor="Black" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray"
                                alternatingrowstyle-forecolor="Black" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#007b5e" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"borderstyle="Solid"
                                gridlines="Both" BorderColor="#000" OnRowCommand="gvClientGrid_RowCommand">
                                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                    <span class="bg-danger text-white rounded text-align-content-center btn btn-md">No records to be displayed at this time</span>
                                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Member Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="f-5" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="membername" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="f-5" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="lastname" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="f-5" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="firstname" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="f-5" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="contactemail" />
                                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Telephone" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="f-5" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="telephone" />
                                    <asp:ButtonField Text="Details" CommandName="details" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-md fs-5 btn-dark text-white" />
                                    <asp:ButtonField Text="Pwd Reset" CommandName="reset" ItemStyle-Width="12%" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-md fs-5 btn-dark text-white" />      
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
                <div class="d-grid gap-1 col-sm-4 mx-auto">
                    <asp:button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear All" OnClick="btnClear_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
                <div class="d-grid gap-1 col-sm-4 mx-auto">
                    <asp:button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Exit Clients" OnClick="btnExit_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-lg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

In the code-behind I have the RowCommand event, as follows:

```
protected void gvClients_RowCommand ( object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e ) {
            var id = gvClients.DataKeys [int.Parse ( e.CommandArgument.ToString ( ) )].Value.ToString ( ); ;
        ...
        }
```

For some reason the compiler can't "see" the gridview control (gvClients), which has a squiggly red line under it.  I don't understand what the issue is here.  Help?

Comment: Is there a master page for this page?

Comment: There is, but it doesn't have any code or functional controls other than some Bootstrap stuff (navbar, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Gee, I would have JUST posted the gv,

But, check this line:

```
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#007b5e" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"borderstyle="Solid"
```

You need a space after "White", and thus:

```
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#007b5e" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" borderstyle="Solid"
                                                             ^
```

Comment: I posted all of the code because the gridview is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel, so I wanted to be sure that wasn't part of the issue.  I did fix what you pointed out, but it didn't change anything.  I get the error "gvClients does not exist in the current context".